# False boolean value statement not inserting to database

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I have a JSON array that looks like this:

```
{
    "operation": "update_original_team_member",
    "teamMember": {
        "teamMemberPresent": false,
        "unique_id": "5a5b7f6b835408.50059003",
        "user_unique_id": "59bea8b7d56a63.33388595"
    }
}
```

and I am trying to insert it into mySQL database but it is failing every time, but when I change the false to true, it works, any ideas why this is?

The table it is being inserted to is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE team_member (
    team_member_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    unique_id varchar(23) NOT NULL,
    fullName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    user_unique_id varchar(23) NOT NULL,
    present boolean NOT NULL,
    date_last_present datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    points int(50) NULL,
    team_id int (11) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (team_member_id),
     FOREIGN KEY (`team_id`)
    REFERENCES `ocidb_CB9s149919`.`team` (`team_id`)
    );
```

The JSON array is being sent from Retrofit (Retrofit is a REST Client for Android) and is received as so:

```
if ($operation == 'update_original_team_member') {

            if (isset($data -> teamMember) && !empty($data -> teamMember)&& isset($data -> teamMember -> teamMemberPresent)
                && isset($data -> teamMember -> unique_id)&& isset($data -> teamMember -> user_unique_id)){

              $teamMember                 = $data             -> teamMember;
              $teamMemberPresent          = $teamMember       -> teamMemberPresent;
              $unique_id                  = $teamMember       -> unique_id;
              $user_unique_id             = $teamMember       -> user_unique_id;


              echo $fun -> updatePresent($teamMemberPresent,$unique_id, $user_unique_id);

              } else {


              echo $fun -> getMsgInvalidParam();

            }
```

This is being past to the following function:

```
public function updatePresent($teamMemberPresent,$unique_id, $user_unique_id){

     $db = $this -> db;

     if (!empty ($teamMemberPresent)&& !empty ($unique_id)&& !empty ($user_unique_id)){

         $result = $db -> updatePresent($teamMemberPresent,$unique_id, $user_unique_id);

         if ($result) {

            $response["result"] = "success";
            $response["message"] = "Active Students Have Been Recorded!";
            return json_encode($response);

         } else {

            $response["result"] = "failure";
            $response["message"] = "Unable To Update Details, Please Try Again";
            return json_encode($response);

         }
         } else {

      return $this -> getMsgParamNotEmpty();

            }

}
```

The query I am using to update is:

```
public function updatePresent($teamMemberPresent,$unique_id, $user_unique_id){



$sql = "UPDATE team_member SET present = :present WHERE unique_id = :unique_id AND user_unique_id = :user_unique_id";


// Prepare statement
$query = $this ->conn ->prepare($sql);

// execute the query
$query->execute(array(':present' => $teamMemberPresent,':unique_id' => $unique_id, ':user_unique_id' => $user_unique_id));

if ($query) {

return true;        

} else {

return false;

    }
 }
```

I have used postman to try and isolate the issue and I have narrowed it down the to `$teamMemberPresent` variable failing, stating that it is empty when it is interting as false but I haven't a clue why. As I mentioned earlier, when its set to true, the query works fine.

Any guidance would be really appreciated.

Comment: what is the value of `$teamMemberPresent` within the function when it is called?

Comment: How are you calling `updatePresent`, and what values are you passing to it? Without that information, your question is impossible to answer.

Comment: The values are all in the JSON array (at the beginning of my question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `updatePresent()` function, this code does not recognize the data as valid, and skips the database update:

```
if (!empty ($teamMemberPresent)&& !empty ($unique_id)&& !empty ($user_unique_id)){
 ...
```

The reason is that `empty($teamMemberPresent)` returns true if its argument has a `false` value.

http://php.net/empty says:

> A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE.

You should use `isset($teamMemberPresent)` instead.

Here's a demo:

```
if (isset($data -> teamMember)
&& !empty($data -> teamMember)
&& isset($data -> teamMember -> teamMemberPresent)
&& isset($data -> teamMember -> unique_id)
&& isset($data -> teamMember -> user_unique_id))
{       
        echo "Should all be OK\n";  

        $teamMember                 = $data             -> teamMember;
        $teamMemberPresent          = $teamMember       -> teamMemberPresent;

        if (!empty($teamMemberPresent)) {
                echo "Confirmed, not empty\n";
        } else {
                echo "Woops! It's empty\n";
        }
}
```

Output:

```
Should all be OK
Woops! It's empty
```

Comment: I have just added the `isset` in the section you suggested, and it has solved my issue! I thought that because I checked `isset` before passing to the `function updatePresent` that it wasn't necessary to check it again, but apparently, it was. Thanks for your suggestion, I'll accept your answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Cast you boolean variable to int.

```
$query->execute(array(':present' => (int) $teamMemberPresent,':unique_id' => $unique_id, ':user_unique_id' => $user_unique_id));
// this one -> (int) $teamMemberPresent
```